# Exception when installing tableau with data directory option

Tags: tableau

Hello I am creating azure VM image with Tableau server based on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS. The problem arises when I attempt to execute `./initialize-tsm --accepteula -d /tableau` command. (I am able to succesfylly initialise tabelau without -d option). I have made sure that `/tableau` directory is owned by tableau user and tableau group. Any ideas why this error ocurs?

If you need any other code/logs please let me know and I will provide it

Thank you for your help

#### Exception durinig intialisation

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tableau/temp/jna--1552905086/jna7656128698801184278.tmp: /tableau/temp/jna--1552905086/jna7656128698801184278.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object
          at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
          at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
          at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
          at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:947)
          at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922)
          at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190)
          at com.tableausoftware.utils.net.NetworkAddressProvider$LibC.<clinit>(NetworkAddressProvider.java:288)
          at com.tableausoftware.utils.net.NetworkAddressProvider.getLocalHostname(NetworkAddressProvider.java:81)
          at com.tableausoftware.utils.net.NetworkAddressProvider.<init>(NetworkAddressProvider.java:62)
          at com.tableausoftware.installer.UserSettingsManager.<init>(UserSettingsManager.java:110)
          at com.tableausoftware.installer.AbstractInstaller.constructDependencies(AbstractInstaller.java:122)
          at com.tableausoftware.installer.InstallerMain.constructDependencies(InstallerMain.java:81)
          at com.tableausoftware.installer.AbstractOperationRunner.run(AbstractOperationRunner.java:164)
          at com.tableausoftware.installer.AbstractOperationRunner.runInstance(AbstractOperationRunner.java:116)
          at 
    com.tableausoftware.installer.AbstractOperationRunner.execute(AbstractOperationRunner.java:103)
          at com.tableausoftware.installer.AbstractOperationRunner.execute(AbstractOperationRunner.java:57)
          at com.tableausoftware.installer.InstallerMain.execute(InstallerMain.java:181)
          at com.tableausoftware.installer.InstallerMain.main(InstallerMain.java:188)
         ERROR: TSM services returned status 1
```

#### list of commands that I use to provision vm

```bsh
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get -y install gdebi-core
apt-get install curl -y
curl https://downloads.tableau.com/esdalt/2019.3.0/tableau-server-2019-3-0_amd64.deb --output tableau-server-2019-3-0_amd64.deb
gdebi -n tableau-server-2019-3-0_amd64.deb
curl https://downloads.tableau.com/tssoftware/Tableau-SDK-Linux-64Bit-10-3-25.deb --output Tableau-SDK-Linux-64Bit-10-3-25.deb
gdebi -n Tableau-SDK-Linux-64Bit-10-3-25.deb
bash ~/prepare_vm_disks.sh
useradd --user-group -d /tableau tableau
chown tableau:tableau /tableau
cd /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/scripts.20193.19.0913.2225
./initialize-tsm --accepteula -d /tableau
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear I have resolved the problem. It turned out that the data disk I have been mounting for Tableu data directory had `noexec` mount option specified in in script I was using for disk discovery and mounting. Quite embarrassing on my side really.